# fetching rating data from database to JSON array in php rest api

Tags: php, mysql, json, api

i'm developing an **api** that'll provide a rating value for each student. It's a two stage rating system  [Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0giw.jpg) . In **STAGE-I** UI view, student list appears with student name and rating points. To rate a student, one have click on the rating stars & **STAGE-II** appears with some rating categories. The rating of each student depends on this part. Each category's a rating value as **Sum_of_Rating_value/rating_numbers**. After rating all categories (or rating 2/3 of these), the result will be re-rated as **Sum_of_ALL_Category/Category_number** and be placed in **STAGE-I** student list UI view. N.B.:I've done all the calculations.
 
Now when i call the data in QUERY as:

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass","DB_NAME") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));<br><br>
$stu_id=$_POST['stu_id'];<br><br>
 $sql_query = " SELECT *, FORMAT(((SELECT SUM(view_rating.total_points+view_rating2.total_points2+view_rating3.total_points3+view_rating4.total_points4+view_rating5.total_points5) FROM view_rating,view_rating2,view_rating3,view_rating4,view_rating5)  / (SELECT SUM(view_rating.rating_number+view_rating2.rating_number2+view_rating3.rating_number3+view_rating4.rating_number4+view_rating5.rating_number5) FROM view_rating,view_rating2,view_rating3,view_rating4,view_rating5) ),1) as average_rating,(select count(review)  from review WHERE stu_id=14 )as review_count FROM student_info WHERE stu_id='$stu_id' ";<br><br>
$user_array=array();<br>
$main_array=array(); <br><br>
 $result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql_query);<br>
 while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{<br>
    $user_array['stu_id']=$row['stu_id'];<br>
    $user_array['name']=$row['name'];<br>
    $user_array['mobile']=$row['mobile'];<br>
    $user_array['email']=$row['email'];<br>
    $user_array['gender']=$row['gender'];<br>
    $user_array['Dept']=$row['Dept'];<br>
    $user_array['blood_group']=$row['blood_group'];<br>
$user_array['average_rating']=$row['average_rating'];<br>
$user_array['review_count']=$row['review_count'];<br>
array_push($main_array,$user_array);<br>
}<br><br>
$mainarray=array("STUDENTS"=>$main_array);<br>
$jsonData = json_encode($mainarray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);<br>
echo $jsonData;<br>
?>
```

In JSON array, it doesn't pull **average_rating** and **review_count** from DB. It only shows **null**.
But when i define stu_id as 2 or 3 in WHERE clause, it shows  the same average_rating and same review  not only in the defined stu_id but also in the other ids.
 But I want exact average_point/review fro each student.
 
I think, the problem lies in the QUERY. So, can anyone help me out???

Comment: seems error in code. why <br> tag like ?you should echo <br>

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: problem with the query.... can you help me out, Sir?

Comment: Show us the structure of your database. When I see `view_rating.total_points`, `view_rating2.total_points2`, `view_rating3.total_points3` etc I get the feeling that the database design might be an issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $sql_query is really hard to read; I would break it up into smaller pieces.

Why do you have `(select count(review) from review WHERE stu_id=14 )as review_count` as part of the query?

What's special about the magic number 14? It's generally a bad idea to have magic numbers in your code. Who is student 14? Why is this number hard-coded instead of using $stu_id or some other variable? This is probably related to why you're not getting a review_count.

If you do get a review_count when you change this to `WHERE stu_id=2` or `WHERE stu_id=3`, it's probably either because `review` has entries for students `2` and `3` but not for student `14`, or because $stu_id was either `2` or `3` when you made the query. I'd guess the latter.

Since your overall query is wrapped in an outermost `FROM student_info WHERE stu_id='$stu_id'`, it should only grab information for the student with id $stu_id. If that id is not equal to 14, there's no information for student 14, so when you try to run the code for the review count on student 14 it doesn't find anything (you're searching in a dataset that was already filtered to only have data for student $stu_id).

I'm not sure about this because the code is very hard to read as it is currently structured, but I'd guess that's a good starting point for troubleshooting.